# value for two parameters not being shown ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

When I go to my browser, the values for 'name' and 'location' are displayed but not the values entered for 'start' and 'end' (which are dates). Here is the code I have for my 'show'html and controller.

show.html.erb:

```
<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @trip.name %>
</p>

<p>
 <strong>Location:</strong>
 <%= @trip.location %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Start Date:</strong>
  <%= @trip.start %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>End Date:</strong>
  <%= @trip.end %>
</p>
```

trips_controller.rb:

```
class TripsController < ApplicationController
def show
    @trip = Trip.find(params[:id])
end

def new
end

def create
    #render plain: params[:trip].inspect
    @trip = Trip.new(trip_params)

    @trip.save
    redirect_to @trip
end

private
    def trip_params
        params.require(:trip).permit(:name, :location, :start, :end)
    end
end
```

trip.rb:

```
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20151016023421) do
  create_table "trips", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "location"
    t.string   "name"
    t.date     "start"
    t.date     "end"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end
end
```

In my rails console:

```
2.2.3 :013 > Trip.first
  Trip Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "trips".* FROM "trips"  ORDER BY "trips"."id"         ASC LIMIT 1
 => #<Trip id: 1, location: "we", name: "a", start: nil, end: nil,  created_at: "2015-10-21 03:17:45", updated_at: "2015-10-21 03:17:45", user_id:  nil>

2.2.3 :014 > Trip.create(name: 'test', location: 'test location', start:  '2015-10-21', end: '2015-10-27')
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "trips" ("name", "location", "start", "end",    "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["name", "test"],   ["location", "test location"], ["start", "2015-10-21"], ["end", "2015-10-27"],  ["created_at", "2015-10-21 04:44:18.436966"], ["updated_at", "2015-10-21  04:44:18.436966"]]
   (22.7ms)  commit transaction
 => #<Trip id: 11, location: "test location", name: "test", start: "2015-10- 21", end: "2015-10-27", created_at: "2015-10-21 04:44:18", updated_at: "2015-10- 21 04:44:18", user_id: nil>
```

Comment: perhaps my model wasn't generated correctly?

Comment: please show your `schema.rb` file as well. Also, what do you see if you type: `Trip.first` in your rails console?

Comment: Can you create a trip in your rails console using this: `Trip.create(name: 'test', location: 'test location', start: '2015-10-21', end: '2015-10-27')`? Please do this and show me the output.

Comment: Again, posted above.

Comment: right, so it worked. if you visit: `localhost:3000/trips/11` you should be able to see the values properly.

Comment: YOU'RE RIGHT. The convention in which you enter the dates matter. Thanks for helping me through this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `@trip.start` and `@trip.end` are `nil`, that's why you don't see it in the browser. Try doing this way to confirm that:

```
<p>
  <strong>Start Date:</strong>
  <%= @trip.start.inspect %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>End Date:</strong>
  <%= @trip.end.inspect %>
</p>
```

see if it shows `nil`s for their value now.

It will show the value in the browser if the value is present.

Comment: yeah it says nil. Why for these two date values?

Comment: So, when your `start` and `end` column's values will be present, they will show up in the page. Nothing wrong with your view.

Comment: but i entered in a date in the form on the browser. is it because i didn't enter the date in the correct convention?

Comment: It depends how you saved those values in the database. If you save the values properly like you did for name and location, then those will show up too.

Comment: could be. Make sure you save the values in the database correctly. Then it will work properly.

Comment: do you mean in my schema.rb file? I did everything the same as my name and location params.

Comment: I can't tell exactly without seeing more detail. Try to create a `Trip` object from the rails console and see if you can save all the fields. Then see that trip object in the browser.

Comment: @coderk was my answer helpful to find/solve your problem? Let me know if you have any more question.

Comment: hmm...I was able to save all fields except the 'start' and 'end' fields...do you know why that is?

Comment: please show the `Trip` model code and how you are trying to save the trip object.

Comment: This is all that is in my model code...I think this is all that was generated by rails.

    class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
    end

Comment: Please edit/update your question with new information.